# Why FindMinimum crashes the kernel in specific situation

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization, kernel, crash

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

I have found that `FindMinimum` crahses is a certain situation. Here is my minimal working example:

```
length = 50;
roundoffErrorMatrix = 
  10^-10*(# + Transpose@# &@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {length, length}]);
costMatrix = IdentityMatrix@length + roundoffErrorMatrix;
variables = Table[Unique[], {i, 1, length}];

FindMinimum[{variables.costMatrix.variables, Thread[variables >= -1]},
  variables]

FindMinimum[{x^2, x >= -1}, x]
```

### Explanation of code

In the minimal working example there two calls to `FindMinimum`. The second call is just a simple example to show some bad behavior that happens; I will explain more after discussing the first call to `FindMinimum`.

The first call to `FindMinimum` just basically minimizes the square length of a vector (since `costMatrix` is essentially the identity matrix), subject to the constraint that the components are all greater than -1.

To set up the first call to `FindMinimum`, I first pick `length` which gives the dimensionality of the minimization problem. Then I make a simulated round off error matrix, which is necessary to reproduce the error. Then I set my `costMatrix` equal to this round off error matrix plus the identity matrix. Lastly, I create an array for the variables for `FindMinimum`.

### Description of Behavior

Now I will describe what happens when I run the code. I have the code in three cells: the setup, and the two calls to `FindMinimum`. The first cell runs just fine. When I run the second cell (first call to `FindMinimum`) for the first time, it does just fine.

After running the second cell once, I can do two things, both of which crash the kernel. The first thing I can do is to repeatedly run the second cell again. The other thing that crashes the kernel is to run the third cell once.

### Necessary conditions

There are a surprising number of conditions for this bug to occur. There are three by my count:

1. The dimensionality of the problem (`length`) must be greater or
   equal to 50.
2. The `costMatrix` must have the round off error included. Simply
   `IdentityMatrix` or `N@IdentityMatrix` will not do.
3. The constraints must be present.

I am using Mathematica 11.0.0.0 on Linux x86 (64 bit). Why does this crash occur, and what is a good workaround?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I have filed a bug report. For a workaround, please try `Method -> "InteriorPoint"`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I confirm that I also observe this bug (Linux x86 64-bit, Mathematica v-11.0.1.0). FindMinimum kills the Kernel when used twice. The Method -> "InteriorPoint" trick works for me (no more crashes). I also have  (Linux x86 64-bit, Mathematica v-10.0.0.1), in that case, everything is ok (works with the default FindMinimum method). Concerning necessary conditions, in my case the crashes occur with less than 50 variables and yes I have (bound) constraints.

Comment: On my system the crash appears starting from `length = 90;` with version 11.0.1; with version 10.4.1 its OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: This bug has been fixed in the [just released](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/03/16/the-rd-pipeline-continues-launching-version-11-1/) Mathematica 11.1.

---

A good workaround was suggested by [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133428/why-findminimum-crashes-the-kernel-in-specific-situation#comment359945_133428).

> For a workaround, please try Method -> "InteriorPoint".

This workaround worked for me. In particular, I can now run the first `FindMinimum` command for the code listing in my question as many times as I want, and the second `FindMinimum` command does not cause a crash either. Even better, the solution found with this option seems to be more accurate. I also did not notice a slow down when I applied this workaround to the original application.